# node.js program using mssql module - connecting to a SQL Server database fails

Tags: sql-server

I've got this very simple node.js program. The program adds a record to an SQL Server database. I'm trying to code it as a synchronous operation.

It returns an error:

> "config.server" property is required and must be of type string.

However the property exists and is a string.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sql_server = require('mssql');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', event);
    var DB_status;
    DB_status=Add_to_DB(event);
    if (DB_status=="OK") {
      var response = {
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "{\"result\": \"Success.\"}"
      };
    }
    else {
      var response = {
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "{\"result\": \"Database Error - " + DB_status + ".\"}"
      };
    };
    callback(null,response);
}

async function Add_to_DB (event) {
    let DB_status="OK";
    const config = {
      user: 'sa',
      password: 'sapassword',
      database: 'serverless-example',
      server: 'serverless-example.cilqefqosmtc.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
    };

    var sql = 'INSERT INTO UserTbl(Name,Email,Message)';
    sql = sql + ' VALUES(\"' + event.name + '\",\"' + event.email + '\",\"' + event.message + '\")';

    try {
      let dbConn = await sql_server.connect();
      let request = new sql_server.Request(dbConn);
      await request.query(sql);
    }
    catch (err) {
      // Error running our SQL Query
      console.error("ERROR: Exception thrown running SQL", err);
      DB_status=err;
    }
    return DB_status;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a node guy (probably should add tag), but it looks like you're setting up your config variable, but then not using it with your sql connection at all. Do you need to pass it into your connection somehow?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is a typo which I didn't spot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all.
There is a typo there which I did not spot - I did not end up using the conif variable.

THanks to all for looking